# How to render API output to UI? It's not rendering inside the scaffold's container

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart

Please someone help. Here is my code. Why is not the output of the API (stored in parse) showing in the UI in the blue container. Thanks.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:api/model/pin_code.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  Map parse = <dynamic,dynamic>{};

  Future<dynamic> getPincode(String pincode) async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/${pincode}'));
    return compute(parsePinCode, response.body);
  }

  List<PinCode> parsePinCode(String responseBody) {
    final parse = jsonDecode(responseBody);
    print(parse);
    final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    final yourResponse =  parsed.map<PinCode>((json) => PinCode.fromJson(json)).toList();
    print('Here you go ${parsed[0]["PostOffice"][0]["Name"]}');
    return yourResponse;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final TextEditingController pinCode = TextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Pin code Rest API Demo '),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: height * 0.09),
          TextFormField(
            controller: pinCode,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: height * 0.05,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                print("DATA FETCHED ${pinCode.text}");
                final mapResponse = getPincode(pinCode.text);
                print(mapResponse.toString());
              },
              child: const Text("Search")),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text('Here you go $parse'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried putting parse as a global variable but didn't get the API's output rendered in the UI despite calling it in the scaffold's container that I want to render it in.

Comment: also, you are not calling `setState` having fetched the data

Comment: Okay calling setState now, inside it I am updating the API response to be rendered in container. May you please tell with what data type should I initialize the variable parsed with so that I can access it inside setstate()?

Comment: Here's my updated code with setstate

Comment: I'm not seeing any edits (and still no setstate)

Comment: Actually not getting the opportunity to post the updated code here in comment, sorry

Answer (score 0):

In method `parsePinCode`, you assigned json value in local variable `parse`

Change from `final parse = jsonDecode(responseBody);`  to `parse = jsonDecode(responseBody);`

Comment: Okay. May you please tell with what data type should I initialize the variable parsed globally  with so that I can access it inside onpressed's setstate()? Here is parsed variable - parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();  Only declaring it and initializing "parsed" variable later with "late" modifier also is not giving the output to screen. Thanks.

Comment: You can just assign with `setState` or else you call call at before return with empty as `setState(() {});`